# Filtering CSV file based on string name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

I'm trying to get specific columns of a csv file (that Header contains "SOF" in case). Is a large file and i need to copy this columns to another csv file using Shell.

I've tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk ' {
i=1
j=1

while ( NR==1 )
  if ( "$i" ~ /SOF/ )
  then
   array[j] = $i
   $j += 1
  fi
$i += 1

for ( k in array ) 
 print array[k]

}' fil1.csv > result.csv
```

In this case i've tried to save the column numbers that contains "SOF" in the header in an array. After that copy the columns using this numbers.

Comment: note that looping through arrays in awk is done like this: `for (item in array)`. Your are currently using a Basy syntax instead.

Comment: You completely misunderstand awk syntax and semantics. Awk is not shell, it is a completely different tool with it's own language. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and start working through the first few examples.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui , but still does not working :( , i think my logic is right but the result csv is empty, and the script is running in a loop...

Comment: As @EdMorton suggested, start with a small example, since you are mixing many basic concepts here.

Comment: The keywords `contains`, `then` and `fi` are not keywords in `awk`.  You probably need a regex and `~` for `contains`; the rest just needs converting from shell-ish to Awk.  Also, `$i` in Awk is very different from `$i` in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary note: contrary to what one may infer from the code included in the OP, the values in the CSV are delimited with a semicolon.

Here is a solution with two separate commands:

- the first parses the first line of your CSV file and identifies which fields must be exported. I use `awk` for this.
- the second only prints the fields. I use `cut` for this (simpler syntax and quicker than `awk`, especially if your file is large)

The idea is that the first command yields a list of field numbers, separated with ",", suited to be passed as parameter to `cut`:

```
# Command #1: identify fields
fields=$(awk -F";" '
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            if ($i ~ /SOF/) {
                fields = fields sep i
                sep = ","
            }
        print fields
        exit
     }' fil1.csv
)

# Command #2: export fields
{ [ -n "$fields" ] && cut -d";" -f "$fields" fil1.csv; } > result.csv
```

Comment: The result.csv file have the same content of fil1.csv when i compile the script

Comment: @LorD Can you `echo "$fields"` please?

Comment: Using echo to show the content of the variable fields, just return 1.

Comment: The first column of the file don't contains SOF

Comment: @LorD I tested my solution with `gawk` with and without POSIX mode (`--posix`) and it worked. What is your `awk`?

Comment: @LorD On my machine `awk --version` yields `GNU Awk 4.0.1`. Moreover, on my Linux Debian machines, `/etc/alternatives/awk` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/gawk`. With `mawk`, you must use `mawk -W version` to get `mawk 1.3.3`. Maybe your manual (`man awk`) may tell you what `awk` it is.

Comment: @LorD BTW, you say that `result.csv` is identical to `fil1.csv` and that the `fields` variable is `1`. This is not possible. Are you sure to have properly copy-pasted my code?

Comment: mawk 1.3.3 here

Comment: @LorD It works with `mawk`. I tested with a CSV whose first line is `1,2,fooSOF,4,5,6,7,SOFbar,9,fooSOFbar` and I got `3,8,10` in the variable `fields`. Aren't your values delimited by a comma in your CSV file? You should post a sample of your CSV file in your question.

Comment: The values are delimited by a semicolon.

Comment: @LorD That explains everything. You should have mentioned that in your question, both of us would not have lost time on this. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
       NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/SOF/) {col=i; break}} 
             {print $col}' file
```

there is no handling if the sought out header doesn't exist so should print the whole line.

Comment: Apparently, OP wants to select _all_ the fields named "...SOF...", not just one

Answer (score 0):

[This link might be helpful for you :](http://bconnelly.net/working-with-csvs-on-the-command-line/)

One of the useful commands you probably need is "cut"

**cut -d , -f 2 input.csv**

Here number 2 is the column number you want to cut from your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

try this one out :

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=a[i]" "$i}END{for (i in a ){ print a[i] } }'  filename  | grep SOF | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=a[i]" "$i}END{for (i in a ){ print a[i] } }'
```

Comment: the grep SOF does not look for SOF in the first occurrence so youmay want to replace it with awk '/$1 ~ "SOF"/{print $0}' and the full commands becomes like this :    awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=a[i]" "$i}END{for (i in a ){ print a[i] } }' SOF.txt  | awk '/$1 ~ "SOF"/{print $0}' | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=a[i]" "$i}END{for (i in a ){ print a[i] } }'